# Play youtube video with explicit control

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to play youtube video in a html page with a custom play button like [**this fiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/A3jgy/4/v).

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn">Play</button>

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="yt" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/6eK-W32IME0?fs=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;hl=en_US" width="330" height="200"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/></object>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var yt = document.getElementById("yt");

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = play;

function play() {
    yt.playVideo();            
}
```

The code works fine in JSFiddle, but when I put same thing in a text file and execute, the video is not playing. Please suggest me in this regard, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Link to the JsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry i was not able to make the above link as clickable.

Comment: what do you mean by text file - is it a HTML page?

Comment: yes, I put all the code in a html file. But explicit play button is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, you are trying to access element via `document.getElementById`, which depends on where you write the `<script>` tag. Fiddle's script loading process or location may be different from normal browsers. As per your code, if the `<script>` tag is before `<button>`, then it will not work, where as if you put `<script>` after `<object>`, then it will work.

I modified your code as below which i was able to run successfully.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        var yt = document.getElementById("yt");

        document.getElementById('btn').onclick = play;
    }

    function play() {
        yt.playVideo();            
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<button id="btn">Play</button>

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="yt" 
    data="http://www.youtube.com/v/6eK-W32IME0?fs=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;hl=en_US" 
    width="330" height="200">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

**Page has to be loaded via http protocol because of SOP reasons, browser will not allow access to player if loaded as file protocol**

Comment: Still the custom play button is not working, on click of the button video is not playing

Comment: i have tried the same code in chrome browser and found it is working. can you check the developer console for any error or exception?

Comment: i hope you are trying to launch the page via http://localhost/ as you know if you open it as file://, then it will not allow you to play.

Comment: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'playVideo'  this is the eror displayed in chrome and TypeError: yt.playVideo is not a function is the error in Firefox

Comment: ya its working now, sorry I didnt use local host till now. Thanks for the answer